# Could Pycharm show error syntax tips only?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, pycharm

In my case,Pycharm will show me so many syntax tips,including error,warning,weak warning and so on .
[syntax tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCc2c.png)

But,I only want to focus on the error syntax tips.How should I set the Settings in Pycharm?

Comment: the error is the only thing preventing it from running, so try running it and look at the output... It will give you the line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may change the inspection settings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-inspection-severities.html